# Can I install Fingerprint Device SDK as well as run . exe file in Windows 10 IoT Core?

Tags: c#, windows, sdk, windows-10-iot-core, zkteco

I have a ZK Teco Fingerprint Device and Printing Device and I am building a solution to Print Token when fingerprint matched. I am using C# for building windows form application. Its working absolutely fine but I want to switch  Raspberry Pi 3 Model B instead of General PC or Laptop. 
Is it possible to run .exe file or install SDK on Windows 10 IoT Core ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application(*.exe) can not run on Windows IoT Core. IoT Core is a UWP centric OS and UWP apps are its primary app type. IoT Core supports certain traditional Win32 app types such as Win32 Console Apps and NT Services, but only C++ is supported for developing Win32 apps on IoT Core. More details about development for Windows IoT Core please see this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/tutorials/quickstarter/developapp).